# Is there way to mimic php`s "@" modifier in lua?

Tags: php, syntax, lua

There is one thing in PHP that i personally really like to use - @ modifier, which casts any type of exceptions/error after it into null (when it is safe, of course, in cases when i really dont care about handling any errors at all)

The question is - how can i mimic such behaviour in Lua? May be there is a way to achive similar effect on specially-prepared tables only (with special metatable) - but it seems to be hard to make it right with all __* stuff.

The point is in making it as close to syntactical sugar as possible. 
Any suggestions?

UPD: lets assume developer is fully aware of all gotchas of error suppression (or developer just turned on the dark side suppressing all errors in the galaxy for the sake of dark emperor %) )

Comment: `@` is the death of developer in case of system, app, program, logic failure

Comment: @Shakti: I disagree. It is bad style, but there are valid reasons for suppressing errors. One being that an error is not necessarily fatal for the program flow.

Comment: @IPv6: is `pcall` what you are looking for? `p` stands for "protected" here.

Comment: To suppress errors is actually a rather expensive operation in PHP, so don't use it in performance-critical contexts.

Comment: pcall seems to be related! so the question can be slightly rewrited: how to silently wrap expression into callable object? i just what syntactical sugar, again... in cases where normal error handling REALLY not needed at all

Comment: When you write code in Lua, you must write it in Lua. Do not bring concepts from other languages just because you like them. Change your mindset instead — this is much more productive.

Comment: not agree... programming languages are made to make life easier and there is no need in self-restriction, imho. back to the question - there are some typical situations where error suppression will save coding time, there is no intention to use it blindly

Comment: @IPv6: Every language has its own "style". If you are trying to merge different languages, just to satisfy your mind, you will make the results even worse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the `@` notation in PHP, but I've seen this "don't throw errors" behaviour in ruby (`... rescue nil`) and java (`try{...}catch(Exception e){}`).

Assuming that this is what you want, the thing that most resembles that in Lua is `pcall` (see [PiL 8.1](http://www.lua.org/pil/8.4.html)).

If the "code you want to be safe about" is inside a function called `foo` then the "safe version" of `foo(bar, baz)` would be `pcall(foo, bar, baz)`.

If you don't have a function, but a bunch of code, then you will have to use pcall + an anonymous function.

```
pcall(function() <your code here> end)
```

I warn you that in general, as others are saying there are no good reasons to "throw away" the error.

If you are doing this, I recommend you at least to be explicit about it in your code with a comment or similar:

```
if not pcall(foo, bar, baz) then
  -- Do nothing on error. 
end
```

Otherwise, it's easy to miss that `pcall` call.

Comment: thanks! just read about pcall more closely - this is what i looking for indeed

Answer (score 1):

Not really the answer to this question, but I feel obliged to respond to this question with 'the best answer'. You should **never** use error suppression. Worst case scenario you alter the error_reporting of your application on publication area. Best: handle them!

Comment: There is always balance between development speed/completeness and to be honest Lua has a lot more gotchas in other areas... but i love this lanuage :) the question is to how to spend more time on what really matters and skip tedious and not-really-needed steps wraping thing in ifs, etc

Comment: i mean there are cases when this steps just a waste of time. not in production code of any kind, of course

Comment: `@` really should not be used in any PHP program, ever.